# \addcontentsline{toc}{section} lists incorrect number

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

Using the report class (no option to change this), I'm trying to accomplish this format: Chapter > Scenario (section) > ScenarioTask (section) where each chapter starts with a Scenario that is a `\section*`. To maintain the same formatting, I also use \section for the ScenarioTask.
Example:

```
\chapter{ChapterTitle} %to be numbered normally
\section*{Scenario #} scenario text here %to be numbered according to scenario # so Scenario 1 would be 1.0
 \section{ScenarioTask} scenario tasks here in enumerated lists %to be numbered Scenario#.Task#
```

I have the following command that renumbers `\thesection`, labels a section without numbering it and then adds the entry to the toc. I do this so that the entry is in the TOC but it does not have section number. The problem is that all the TOC entries are the same.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\newcounter{ScenarioNo} \stepcounter{ScenarioNo}
\newcommand{\scenario}{%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{ScenarioNo}.\arabic{TaskNo}}
    \section*{Scenario \theScenarioNo}\label{sec:scenario \theScenarioNo}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:scenario \theScenarioNo}}
    \setcounter{TaskNo}{0}
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{ScenarioNo}.\arabic{table}}
\preto{\section}{\stepcounter{TaskNo}}
```

When the command first runs, ScenarioNo is 1. Each time I issue the `\scenario` command, the ScenarioNo is incremented by one because I `\stepcounter{ScenarioNo}` prior to `\scenario`. This is not working for the TOC entries. I have to be making this more complicated than necessary.

```
\chapter{Chapter1Title}
\scenario
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{ScenarioNo}.\arabic{TaskNo}}
\section{ScenarioTask1}
\section{ScenarioTask2}
\stepcounter{ScenarioNo} \scenario
\section{ScenarioTask1}
\section{ScenarioTask2}
\stepcounter{ScenarioNo} \scenario
\section{ScenarioTask1}
\section{ScenarioTask2}
```

Comment: Please provide a 'real' document that is compilable -- your setup isn't very clear at the moment. It should show the usage of `\scenario` etc.

Comment: Well, you add some code, but we have to glue it together to get it running. Again: Provide a **compilable** document, not just fragments

Comment: It's still not compilable ;-) I have some guess why it might fail. And I doubt that the applied strategy is the best one, but let's wait ;-)

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  -- The fragments above are out of context! `\preto` is a `etoolbox` macro -- that package is not in your preamble

Comment: Finding a MWE is too time consuming to strip away code that is not needed to get a MWE. All the packages used are in an external file that is referenced. If you cannot help based on what I've posted, I am okay with that. Appreciate even reading and trying.

Comment: @PepPaddy: The community is here to provide *free* help. Spoonfeeding information will speed up this process of helping, otherwise answers just become a guessing-game...

Comment: As it stands the `\nameref` is the cause of the issue -- it does not expand `\theScenarioNo` and writes the `\theScenarioNo` unexpanded to the `.aux` file. Since `\stepcounter{ScenarioNo}` is used, the `.aux` file and the labels are using the current value (at the time of processing), which is `1`

Comment: Thank you Christian. You were able to explain what I knew was happening but didn't know why. I was able to change the addcontentsline to \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Scenario \theScenarioNo} and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess of what you're after. Perhaps refinements are needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{ScenarioTask}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\newcommand{\scenario}{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \section*{Scenario \thesection}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section \thesection}%
  }
\renewcommand{\theScenarioTask}{\thesection.\arabic{ScenarioTask}}
\newcommand{\scenariotask}{%
  \refstepcounter{ScenarioTask}%
  \section*{Scenario Task \theScenarioTask}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Scenario Task \theScenarioTask}%
}

\begin{document}  

\tableofcontents

\chapter{ChapterTitle} %to be numbered normally

%\section*{Scenario #} scenario text here %to be numbered according to scenario # so Scenario 1 would be 1.0
%\section{ScenarioTask} scenario tasks here in enumerated lists %to be numbered Scenario#.Task#
\scenario
\scenariotask
\scenariotask
\scenariotask

\scenario
\scenariotask
\scenariotask
\scenariotask
\scenariotask

\scenario
\scenariotask
\scenariotask
\scenariotask
\scenariotask
\scenariotask

\end{document}
```